# The initial flutter project of counting on tapping in vs code is not working?

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

On initial bases I was on my flutter project (refering to the video) and then the video editor told something which I had done but then this problem started and everything wrong happened.
When I created the new project on flutter the initial flutter project as well as my previous flutter projects are also not working , it shows **no sound no null** and sometimes **run flutter -h for available flutter commands and options**
Please help

I was expecting the new initial flutter project (of counting) to be run properly but it didn't run , error came as "**run flutter -h for available flutter commands and options**"

Comment: Please include more details. What exact errors are you getting, and what does your code look like

Comment: 1) Start emulator, then in vscode go on run and Start Debugging (F5). Then Post the error in your question. 2)do flutter doctor and show also the results here in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.